# How can i make program press button for me C#

Tags: c#

How can I make console program in C# press and hold numlock7 key for me. So that can run in background even if console app is not selected. Can you please tell me method to do that, or atleast class that can I look into.

Thanks

Comment: I want to use this that in my game(Diablo 3), R would be pressed all the time.

Answer (score 1):

```
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send()
```

Comment: Thanks, really nice. How can I implement that so it holds button down?

Comment: Holding a button down is actually a series of single presses. Why are you doing this?

Comment: Also, this method will send key to forms application, not globaly. For example when I press button on my forms application. I want: if I set focus to my notepad, to write "RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR" in notepad. I know how to do series of single presses.

Comment: @Vely you have to use while loop in that case

Comment: This would only send the key to the current application and not the machine.